# How do I use SVG images for splashscreens on PhoneGap builds?

Tags: ios, cordova, svg, png

I'm trying to use SVG's instead of the massive PNG's for the newly-required splashscreens for PhoneGap builds on PhonGap version cli-6.3.0.

How do I use SVG's instead?

```
            <!-- iPads with retinia display -->
    <splash src="splash-ipad-portrait@2x.svg" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="splash-ipad-landscape@2x.svg" width="2048" height="1536" />
        <!-- non-Retina ipads -->
    <splash src="splash-ipad-portrait.svg" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="splash-ipad-landscape.svg" width="1024" height="768" />
        <!-- iPhone 6/7 Plus -->
    <splash src="splash-plus-portrait.svg" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="splash-plus-landscape.svg" width="2208" height="1242" />
        <!-- iPhone 6/7 -->
    <splash src="splash-iphone6-portrait.svg" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="splash-iphone6-landscape.svg" width="1334" height="750" />
        <!-- iPhone 5 -->
    <splash src="splash-iphone5-portrait.svg" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="splash-iphone5-landscape.svg" width="1136" height="640" />
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not support the use of SVGs for splash screens or images generally.

Xcode can create multiple image sizes at *build time* if you provide a vector PDF and use an asset catalog, but this can't be used for launch screens; merely for providing the different scaled images required to support retina displays without needing to maintain discrete image sizes.

Comment: I regrettably have to up-vote an answer that saddens me.